# Android Studio: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo...: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList

Tags: java, android, exception, android-activity, runtime

The full error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine/app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine.vudataActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList
            at app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine.vudataActivity$PlaceholderFragment.onCreateView(vudataActivity.java:83)
            at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1504)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:942)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1121)
            at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1484)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:571)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1129)
            at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:3791)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1620)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I literraly have no idea what is wrong, spent couple of hours trying to fix but it is still crashing
The idea is to create menu button that (when pressed) opens another activity(vudataactivity.java). This activity has to be able to display some some text by using arrayAdapter and list_item.

Error after Davids suggestion:

```
10-26 14:15:33.924      327-327/app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.createViewFromResource(ArrayAdapter.java:353)
            at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getView(ArrayAdapter.java:323)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1430)
            at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1745)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:670)
            at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:727)
            at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1598)
            at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1260)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
            at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
            at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
            at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Please post the rest of the error from the logcat (ie: the stack trace). That will help pinpoint where the problem is.

Comment: I have updated the question with full error. Please don't leave me alone on this one, i'am lost.

Comment: Whic is line 83 of `vudataActivity.java`?

Comment: R.layout.list_item_vudata,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. In `PlaceHolderFragment.onCreateView()` you do this:

```
listView.setAdapter((android.widget.ListAdapter) dabarForecast);
```

You are casting your data as a `ListAdapter`. That's why it is crashing, because `dabarForecast` is an `ArrayList`, not an adapater. You probably want to do this:

```
listView.setAdapter(vudataAdapter);
```

**EDIT add additional suggestion based on OP comment**

When you call:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> vudataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_vudata,
                        R.id.list_item_vudata_textview,
                        dabarForecast);
```

Android expects that your layout file is a complicated layout in which the outermost item is a container (ViewGroup). It then looks inside that container for the `TextView` with the ID `R.id.list_item_vudata_textview`. Your layout file, however, doesn't contain anything but a single `TextView`. You should therefore create your adapter like this:

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> vudataAdapter =
                new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        getActivity(),
                        R.layout.list_item_vudata,
                        dabarForecast);
```

Comment: Yes, i can understand that you are correct. BUT now i got this:
10-26 14:15:33.924      327-327/app.sunshine.android.example.com.sunshine E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.NullPointerException

(i have added full error on description, because there is to lttle space to write it here)

Comment: You are correct again.  I have commented that line and IT WORKS. But also I would like to say that i wrote it on purpose, because at the moment it contains a single TextView, but i will have to add more elements later. You have given me the right direction to think about. I have realized where was the main problem. It was inside list_item_vudata.xml . The problem was ">" on 5th line. I have no idea how i have managed to overlook this mistake, ">" it ended my "TextView" in an unexpected place and that's why it crashed. THANK YOU David Wasser for giving me the right direction to think about.